# Overwriting init() in python. TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, init

```
class A:
    x = 0

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        A.x += 1

    def __init__(self):
        A.x += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print('Count : %d' % A.x)

    def display(self):
        print('a :', self.a, ' b :', self.b)

a1 = A('George', 25000)
a2 = A('John', 30000)
a3 = A()
a1.display()
a2.display()
print(A.x)
```

**I expect output as:**

a : George  b : 25000

a : John  b : 30000

3

**But I'm getting this error:**

TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

*Help out a beginner*

Thanks.

Comment: You have defined ``__init__`` twice – what do you intend this to do? What do you intend the ``.a`` and ``.b`` attributes of ``a3`` to be?

Comment: I was just curious to see if it would work as a concept of method overloading in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have overloaded methods in a Python class.

This will result in just the second `__init__` staying around and the first one will be discarded:

```
def __init__(self, a, b):  # Will get shadowed and thrown away.
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    A.x += 1

def __init__(self):  # Only this one will be left in the class.
    A.x += 1
```

You can achieve pretty much the same functionality with parameter defaults:

```
def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    A.x += 1
```